# What are the steps to get Wide Tiles working on WP7.8?

Tags: c#, live-tile, windows-phone-7.8

I'm trying to get Application (default tile) wide tiles working in the 7.8 emulator, so far Ive
 - I've followed the advice in this article [Adding Wide Tiles to
   WP7.8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720574%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).
 - I added the extra element to the app manifest
 - I can see my reflection code executes correctly to update the live tile.
 - This is on the 7.8 emulator

However when I try to resize the tile to the wide size I only get the small and medium options in the Emulator UI.
Is there anything I've missed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remote tile images was the issue.
I've worked around this as follows

1. On first App Startup set the tiles to placeholder local images (set a flag in settings to indicate the tile is setup)
2. Set the App tile to the remote images as normal after this

This seems to work fine, I found it mentioned on one of the documentation pages I read for the 10th time last night.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this code previously and its working fine on Emulator.
Make sure that you have added all these three parameters WideBackgroundImage, WideBackBackgroundImage and WideBackContent while calling UpdateTileData. Check the image paths are correct and images are added to your project with Build action as Content.

Comment: The images are remote which I'm thinking could be related from some reading I was doing. It works fine on WP8 though